# Possible to calculate "Goethe spectrum" from normal spectrum

Tags: visible-light, scattering

Is it possible for a given spectrum to calculate an artificial *Goethe spectrum* (sometimes also refereed to as *edge spectrum* or *shadow spectrum*)?

Hereby a *Goethe spectrum* would describe the spacial distribution of intensities when light caters at an edge, an example is given with [this image](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantenspektrum#/media/Datei:KantenspektrumK.jpg) and [this image](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantenspektrum#/media/Datei:Kantenspektrum1.jpg) used on th [Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantenspektrum) about the *Goethe spectrum* (which is unfortunately only available in German).

Now the question is that given a normal (Newtonian) spectrum with intensities per wavelength on the spectrum is it possible to calculate what should probably be called a spacial distribution of intensities which would represent a kind of *pseudo-wavelength-intensities* of a *Goethe-spectrum*? The unit could be the intensity by angle, where the angle is the angle of a polar coordinate system
with the edge used in the experiment as the center of the coordinate system. But what would be the theory to be used, with what formula would it be possible to calculate this scattering and the intensity by angle for each wave-length?